# Design a regular expression for a sentence and its subset

Tags: javascript, regex

For the following two sentences,

```
var first_sentence = 'My cat is sleeping';
var second_sentence = 'My cat is sleeping with a blanket';
```

I have tried to use the following regexp to get both verb (sleeping) and the noun (a blanket).

```
var regex = /My cat is (.+?)\s+with.?(.+)?/gi.exec('My cat is sleeping with a blanket');
console.log(regex);
/*
[ 0 : 'My cat is sleeping with a blanket'
  1 : 'sleeping'
  2 : 'a blanket'
  index : 0
  input : 'My cat is sleeping with a blanket'
  length : 3 ]
*/
```

This regular expression got it well but when I apply it to the first sentence, it returns null, any idea about that ?

```
var regex = /My cat is (.+?)\s+with.?(.+)?/gi.exec('My cat is sleeping');
console.log(regex);
// null
```

Comment: In the first sentence, there is no `with`

Comment: The match fails when it reaches `\s+` which means "1 or more whitespace characters".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first sentence, there is no `\s+with.?(.+)?` part that *requires* some text to be present (1+ whitespaces and then `with`). You need to wrap the part of the pattern that is optional with `(?:....)?`:

```
/My cat is (\S+)(?:\s+with\s+(.*))?/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7P3oad/3)

**Details**:

- `My cat is`  - a literal text
- `(\S+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ non-whitespace symbols
- `(?:\s+with\s+(.*))?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\s+with\s+` - `with` word enclosed with 1+ whitespaces on both sides
  - `(.*)`  - Group 2 capturing any 0+ chars other than line break symbols

JS:

```js
var ss = [ "My cat is sleeping", "My cat is sleeping with a blanket"]; 
var rx = /My cat is (\S+)(?:\s+with\s+(.*))?/i; 
for (var s = 0; s < ss.length; s++) { 
  document.body.innerHTML += "Testing \"<i>" + ss[s] + "</i>\"... ";
  if ((m = ss[s].match(rx))!==null) {
     document.body.innerHTML += "Found: <b>" + m[1] + "</b>" + (m[2] ? " and <b>" + m[2] : "") + "</b><br/>";
   } else {
      document.body.innerHTML += "NOT Matched: <b>" + ss[s] + "</b><br/>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Just noticed you do not care for the end of string, removed it from the pattern. `.*` will match up the whole rest of the line.